# Dig command repated SERVER value

Tags: bash, dns, dig

I'm exploring the various options of [`dig`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) command. I have disabled all output except the `stats` section:

```sh
$ options="+noanswer +nocmd +nocomments +stats"

$ dig example.com $options
;example.com.           IN  A
;; Query time: 41 msec
;; SERVER: 75.75.75.75#53(75.75.75.75)
;; WHEN: Wed Apr 01 11:59:25 MDT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56

$ dig stackoverflow.com $options
;stackoverflow.com.     IN  A
;; Query time: 49 msec
;; SERVER: 75.75.75.75#53(75.75.75.75)
;; WHEN: Wed Apr 01 11:59:43 MDT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 110
```

Why these two different domains return the same `SERVER`? Every domain that I have tried return the same `SERVER` value.

Comment: I assume that this is the name server used. See: `dig example.com @9.9.9.9 +noanswer +nocmd +nocomments +stats`

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: `75.75.75.75` is the Comcast nameserver. I guess you're a Comcast customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;; SERVER: 75.75.75.75#53(75.75.75.75)
```

Is the DNS [Name-server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_server) used during the `dig` command.

You can confirm this by checking which name-server [your computer uses](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28941/what-dns-servers-am-i-using);

```
$ dig +noanswer +nocmd +nocomments +stats example.com
...
;; SERVER: 172.18.0.254#53(172.18.0.254)
...

$ cat /etc/resolv.conf  | tail -n 1
nameserver 172.18.0.254
```

<sub>I'm using a local custom DNS server, therefore the local ip ;)</sub>